# Openmesh: How to modify mesh faces? (And how to random access component handles?)

Tags: python, openmesh

I just started using OpenMesh in Python. I started off by trying to make a PolyMesh consisting of a single quad. This is what I did:

```
from openmesh import *
mesh = PolyMesh();
vh0 = mesh.add_vertex(PolyMesh.Point(0,0,0));
vh1 = mesh.add_vertex(PolyMesh.Point(1,0,0));
vh2 = mesh.add_vertex(PolyMesh.Point(1,1,0));
vh3 = mesh.add_vertex(PolyMesh.Point(0,1,0));
vh_list = [vh0, vh1, vh2, vh3];
fh0 = mesh.add_face(vh_list);
```

This creates a single quad mesh. Then, wanting to refine the quad once, I thought to try:

```
vh4 = mesh.add_vertex(PolyMesh.Point(0.5,0,0));
vh5 = mesh.add_vertex(PolyMesh.Point(0.5,1,0));
vh_list = [vh4, vh1, vh2, vh5];
fh1 = mesh.add_face(vh_list);
```

The above gives me a `complex edge` error. I understand from one of the other questions on SO that this is because vh_list in the second case does not define a consistent orientation wrt the first face. However, I did not want to add a new face. That is, I thought the operation would simply split fh0 at x = 0.5 and not create a new face attached to fh0 at edge index 1. Can someone say something about how this can be done? I could not find a "split_face" function in the documentation.

Also, how do I access handles of particular edges/mesh components in Python? (I found answers only for C++.) For instance, I know that I can iterate over the edges with,

```
for eh in mesh.edges():
```

but how can I directly get the handle for edge 2 and use it as follows, for example?

```
mesh.split_edge(eh,vh5)
```

Thank you!

**Edit 1**

I found the function `split` in OpenMesh documentation, but it takes as input a single vertexhandle at which I can split the face. And post-splitting, it converts the mesh to a mesh of triangles. I do not want this. I want to split the quadrilateral into two quadrilaterals at x = 0.5. Thank you.

**Edit 2**

I tried an alternate approach: first delete fh0, and then add two new faces fh0 and fh1 based on the refinement I want. I tried doing

```
mesh.delete_face(fh0)
```

and Python segfaulted and exited.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split the face `fh0` into two faces you should delete `fh0` first and then create the two new faces. This should do the job :

```
mesh.delete_face(fh0, deleted_isolated_vertices = False)
mesh.garbage_collection()

fh0 = mesh.add_face(vh0,vh4,vh5,vh3)
fh1 = mesh.add_face(vh4,vh1,vh2,vh5)
```

To verify you get what you want, ask for `print(mesh.face_vertex_indices())`, you should get two lists listing indices of vertices of each face.

Also, to access a known edge handle you can use

```
eh = mesh.edge_handle(edge_index)
```

where `edge_index` is `int`, index of your edge of interest.

Hope this helps,

Charles.